# Андроид. Не вызвывется onDestroy

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

По нажатию на кнопку "back" не всегда вызывается метод onDestroy. Причём никакой зависимости нет, он просто может вызываться, а может не вызываться - как телефону вздумается. При выключении телефона тоже не вызывается. В чём может быть проблема? В этом методе у меня происходит сохранение информации, поэтому это очень критично. При этом метод onPause вызывается, а вот onDestroy уже нет.

Comment: никто не обещает его вызывать. `onSaveInstanceState` при правильном использовании поможет.

Comment: Да, но как его использовать то? Если он сохраняет своё состояние только в случаях когда активити нужно пересоздать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Одна из выдержек из [документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29) гласит, что onDestroy может иногда и не вызываться. При нехватке памяти активити будет убито без вызова onDestroy